# Several implementation for a linked list - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, methods, linked-list, implementation

I have written a simple LinkedList class. I first have a Node class:

```
class Node
{
   public:
       Node* next;
       int value;
       Node(int val)
       {
          value = val;
          next = NULL;
       }

       Node(int val, Node* y)
       {
          value = val;
          next = y;
       }
}
```

then implementation for LinkedList is straightforward, with a `Node* head` member and a `addNode(int value)` member function.

What are other methods to implement a linked list? could give other such implementations or hint at relevant doc?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Um, how about: insert(), delete(), find(), size(), just for starters ?

Comment: You could have a look at the [std::forward_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) interface for inspiration. Youy probably need insertions at the front, back, middle, plus removals. You should also think of how to copy a list object.

Comment: Don't implement anything until you know you actually need it. Otherwise you've fallen into the biggest trap a programmer can fall into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard library defines a doubly-linked list implementation you can use (see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/), for example). I'd advise using that unless you have a very good reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

Boost has some implementations:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/intrusive/slist.html
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/intrusive/list.html

Answer (score 0):

1. `deleteNode`
2. `findNode`
3. Mabe create an iterator.

Also better to use initialisation lists in the constructors and private data members. NULL is for C, use 0 instead.

i.e.

```
class Node
{
   private:
      Node* next;
      int value;
   public:

      Node(int val) : next(0), value(val) {}
      Node(int val, Node *n) : next(n), value(val) {}
      int getVale() { return value}
};
```